# mysql select union all value for date incorrect

Tags: mysql, date, union, key-value

I make a union all from 2 table miele and confmiele like this:

```
 SELECT datamiele, nomemiele, codicemiele, dataconfmiele, '' AS nomeconfmiele, 
        0 AS  codiceconfmiele FROM miele
 UNION ALL
    dataconfmiele, '' AS nomemiele, 0 AS codicemiele, dataconfmiele, nomeconfmiele,
    codiceconfmiele 
 FROM confmiele
```

The result are correct but not the field datamiele and dataconfmiele (are data field type)

```
Result il like:
datamiele
323031332d30392d3031
```

Assigning the value 0 for field number or varchar for fields varchar give me the correct values. ​​But I do not know what assign to date fields?

Comment: you can assign NULL for date fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one by mapping exact alias

```
 SELECT datamiele, 
        nomemiele, 
        codicemiele, 
        dataconfmiele, 
        '' AS nomeconfmiele, 
        0 AS  codiceconfmiele 
 FROM miele
 UNION ALL
 SELECT  dataconfmiele AS datamiele, 
         '' AS nomemiele, 
         0 AS codicemiele, 
         dataconfmiele,
         nomeconfmiele,
         codiceconfmiele 
 FROM confmiele
```

Comment: i try different way: and work just in this way.................. SELECT datamiele, 
        nomemiele, 
        codicemiele, 
        0 AS dataconfmiele, 
        '' AS nomeconfmiele, 
        0 AS  codiceconfmiele 
 FROM miele
 UNION ALL
 SELECT  dataconfmiele AS datamiele, 
         '' AS nomemiele, 
         0 AS codicemiele, 
         dataconfmiele,
         nomeconfmiele,
         codiceconfmiele 
 FROM confmiele  ..................Thank's very much dianuj i had just add 0 AS in the first select of dataconfmiele... i put the correct code for other needed

Answer (score 0):

thank's for the solution
just i correct one thing " '' AS dataconfmiele, " from first select

i left down the solution for others

```
SELECT datamiele, 
        nomemiele, 
        codicemiele, 
        '' AS dataconfmiele, 
        '' AS nomeconfmiele, 
        0 AS  codiceconfmiele 
 FROM miele
 UNION ALL
 SELECT  dataconfmiele AS datamiele, 
         '' AS nomemiele, 
         0 AS codicemiele, 
         dataconfmiele,
         nomeconfmiele,
         codiceconfmiele 
 FROM confmiele
```

thank you very much